# SQL Server Query Analyzer vs Execution Plan

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssms, sql-server-2014

What is the difference between using SQL Server Query Analyzer and just simply highlighting your query, right clicking, and selecting "Show Actual Execution Plan"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Show Actual Execution plan runs your query against exact records available in database whereas Query Analyzer performed the execution based on statistics available in sql engine.